# Int256 in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, int

I've been looking around for implementations of `Int256` and `Int128` in Swift. They seem to be possible to construct now that Swift 4 is out but I haven't found any good implementations.

StackOverflow seems to be devoid of any solutions for now, hopefully this can be a starting place for people in the future looking for this now that Swift 4/Xcode 9.1 are in the wild.

Answer (score 2):

In facing this problem myself, I have managed to find a couple implementations close but not exactly what you’re looking for. Where I get an implication that you’re looking for signed integers (by the use of `Int` instead of `UInt`), I have only been able to find implementations of `UInt`—unsigned integers—at these bit widths.

Here are the links to the repos on GitHub:

- `UInt256`: https://github.com/hyugit/UInt256
- `UInt128`: https://github.com/Jitsusama/UInt128

In any case, these projects are likely good starting points to use toward implementing signed integers at these bit widths. You might be able to check around GitHub to see how implementations of signed and unsigned integers differ at the same bit width, if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has had an implementation for large integers (signed/unsigned 128, 256. 512 and 1024 bit) for a while as part of the [Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate); you can find them in [VecLib](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/veclib).  For example:

[struct vS128](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vs128)
A union containing one vSInt32 vector or four 32-bit integers, representing a 128-bit signed integer.

However, this only applies if you want for `macOS 10.0+`, since it is not available for iOS currently. (As you can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vu256))

Comment: This answers a question that wasn’t asked. The asker is looking for some implementation in pure Swift, presumably with the possibility of use on Linux as well, which is not an option for Accelerate, as Accelerate is proprietary to Apple.

Comment: The original question is clearly tagged as "iOS" and says nothing about linux or other platforms or "pure" Swift so I provided the iOS answer. I answered the question asked, whereas you clearly didn't read the whole question.